# MDI windows in Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, image, mdichild, mdiparent

Right now I have this code to open an image from an MDIParent Window called MDIParent1

```
private void OpenFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    openFileDialog.Filter = "Image Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string FileName = openFileDialog.FileName;
        Process.Start(@FileName);
    }
}
```

This opens a new window with my image fine however I want this to open as a child window to MDIParent1. Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Process.Start(@FileName);` is the same like you double click the file from explorer. So it will open a new window. If you have set default program to open the image, then it will open the program instead.

If you want to do it by C#, create a form with a PictureBox in it. Then instead of calling `Process.Start(@FileName);`, call the form like this:

```
Form1 form = new Form1();
form.MdiParent = this;
form.PictureBox1.ImageLocation = FileName;
form.Open();
```

Comment: i tried this and now it says the picture box is not accessable due to its protection level and the open is missing an assembly reference?

Comment: It is different problem. It has something to do with the access modified. Make your PictureBox1 in Form1 as public and it should solve.